# With Multi Currency enabled, why is the DefaultCurrencyIsoCode and CurrencyIsoCode fields on the user object not available in formula fields?

Tags: formula-field, multi-currency

As the title suggests, for some reason you are unable to access these fields in formula fields (not sure where else they aren't available)

Edit 1: Reason why I need this in the formula field: Based on the record owner's currency, we need to return a specific value. Would be nice to avoid having to use a trigger for this

Comment: can you create a shadow/proxy field on User that has a copy of User.DefaultCurrencyIsoCode (populated by a Flow) that you can then use in formula fields?

Comment: I suppose I can do that. But weird how these fields aren't available out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question directly ("working-as-designed"?) but can suggest a workaround

- Create a new Text field on User: `Default Currency Code Proxy`
- Populate this field in a Flow on every change in value to `User.DefaultCurrencyCode`
- Reference the proxy field in your formulas on the relevant objects via the `Owner:User` polymorphic relationship